# Propagating oozie job last run date to last-value

Tags: hadoop, oozie, sqoop

I have a oozie workflow that runs a sqoop command to do incrementally load data from a table based on the lastupdatedate. 
How do I set the --last-value so that we get records from the last time we ran the job to now?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are importing the data to a hive table , you could query the last updated value from the hive table and pass the value to the sqoop import query.

1. Hive action for the select query based on the logic to retrieve the
   last updated value .
2. Sqoop action for incremental load from thecaptured output of
   previous hive action.

PFB a sudo workflow :

```
<workflow-app name="sqoop-to-hive" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="hiveact"/>
<action name="hiveact">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <script>script.sql</script>
<capture-output/>
    </hive>    
    <ok to="sqoopact"/>
    <error to="kill"/>

<action name="sqoopact">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ydb --table yloc --username root -P --incremental append --last-value ${wf:actionData('hiveact')}</command>
     </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>
<kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

Hope this helps.